# Configuring Firefox 3.0.x to send a Kerberos token

Tags: firefox, single-sign-on, kerberos

I'm trying to convince Firefox 3.0.14 to send a Kerberos token.  I have configured the service correctly and IE will send a Kerberos token (i.e. starting YI..), but after adding the hostname to the network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris and network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris settings in about:config, Firefox only sends an NTLM token.  Here's the (cut down) output from Live Headers:

to server ->

```
GET /testsso.jsp HTTP/1.1
```

<- from server

```
HTTP/1.x 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
```

to server ->

```
GET /testsso.jsp HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Negotiate TlxxxxxxxxQ=
```

<- from server

```
HTTP/1.x 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
```

The server is only interested in a Kerberos token, i.e. one starting in YI, so issues the Unauthorized on the second request, at which point Firefox gives up.

I'm using Windows 2003.  Any thoughts?

J

Answer (score 0):

Kerberos is disabled on a default firefox.

You can enable it, check out the guide here:
http://grolmsnet.de/kerbtut/firefox.html